# Text change to a delete reason in the low quality posts review queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts

When going through the low quality posts review queue, one of the delete reasons is:

> This is commentary on another post, not an answer

The "another" hits my brain wrong, and it's unnecessary. It almost feels as if it means that it's a comment on a different post altogether. If it's a comment, does it need to be qualified? It should simply read:

> This is commentary on a post; not an answer

or

> This is a comment, not an answer

With the existing subtext (“This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.”) remaining.

Comment: I think the rationale behind the word "another" is clarifying that the comment-posted-as-an-answer is a post *in itself*; the comment is intended for a post that is not the post that is the comment.